# Je pourrais vous envoyer un message si je trouve la réponse et si vous le souhaitiez / souhaitez

Tags: imparfait, conditions, présent

> Je pourrais vous envoyer un message si je trouve la réponse et si vous
> le **souhaitiez**.

Est-ce que *souhaiter* à l'imparfait est correct ici ou il faudrait que la phrase soit homogène et il faudrait nécessairement employer le présent ?

> Je pourrais vous envoyer un message si je trouve la réponse et si vous
> le **souhaitez**.

Answer (score 1):

Selon [le Bescherelle](https://bescherelle.com/), concordance des temps dans les subordonnées conjonctives :

> Concordance des temps
> La subordonnée circonstancielle de condition introduite par la conjonction **si** voit le temps de son verbe varier en fonction du temps du verbe de la principale.

1. Le verbe de la principale est à **l'indicatif**, celui de la subordonnée est au même temps que celui de la principale :

> **Si** vous le souhaitez *[présent]*, je peux *[présent]* vous envoyer un message...
> **Si** vous le souhaitiez *[imparfait]*, je pouvais *[imparfait]* vous envoyer un message...

2. Lorsque le verbe de  la principale est au **futur**, le verbe de la subordonnée reste au présent :

> **Si** vous le souhaitez *[présent]*, je pourrai *[futur]* vous envoyer un message...

3. Le verbe de la principale est au **conditionnel**.

   - Lorsqu'il est au **conditionnel présent**, celui de la subordonnée se met à **l'imparfait de l'indicatif** :

   > **Si** vous le souhaitiez *[imparfait]*, je pourrais *[conditionnel présent]* vous envoyer un message...

   - Lorsque le verbe de la principale est au **conditionnel passé**, celui de la subordonnée se met au **plus-que-parfait de l'indicatif** :

   > **Si** vous l'aviez souhaité *[plus-que-parfait indicatif]*, j'aurais pu *[conditionnel passé]* vous envoyer un message...

---

En aucun cas on ne peut avoir la proposition principale au présent de l'indicatif et la subordonnée au conditionnel présent, donc les deux phrases :

> 1. <strike>Je pourrais vous envoyer un message si je trouve la réponse et si vous le souhaitez.</strike>
> 2. <strike>Je pourrais vous envoyer un message si je trouve la réponse et si vous le souhaitiez.</strike>

sont incorrectes.

Deux possibilités :

> 1. Je pourrai *[indicatif futur]* vous envoyer un message si je trouve *[indicatif présent]* la réponse et si vous le souhaitez *[indicatif présent]*.
> 2. Je pourrais *[conditionnel présent]* vous envoyer un message si je trouvais *[indicatif imparfait]* la réponse et si vous le souhaitiez *[indicatif imparfait]*.

Answer (score 0):

La deuxième option semble plus pertinente. Pour voir, essayons d'inverser la phrase :

1. Si vous le souhaitiez, je pourrais (...)
2. Si vous le souhaitez, je pourrais (...)

(ou encore : si vous vouliez vs si vous voulez)

J'opterais pour le présent

Comment: Merci. Je ne pense pas que l'ajout de @Toto soit pertinant. Il est fort probable que Gerrit voulait écrire _pourrai**s**_.

Comment: @Oreste oui en effet, D'ailleurs, c'est ce que je pensais avoir écrit, mais on n'est jamais à l'abri d'un glissement de doigts ;)

Comment: Je n'ai pas compris, vous avez voulu écrire _pourrai_, c'est ça ?

Comment: Excusez-moi pour l'imprécision de ma réaction; je voulais juste recopier vos exemples  à l'identique, avec la phrase inversée pour accentuer la différence entre les deux options. Donc "pourrais" dans les deux cas, puisque votre question était formulée ainsi

Comment: OK, merci, donc cela veut dire que ma remarque est juste. Je remets ce "S" à sa place. :) // Toto a effacé votre "s" dans la deuxième phrase, vous pouvez voir des ajouts si vous cliquez sur "edited" sous votre réponse.

Comment: @Oreste: Le conditionnel n'a pas sa place ici, la concordance des temps impose un futur de l'indicatif.

Comment: @Toto mais c'est sa réponse... Lisez les commentaires de Gerrit... Par contre, vous pourriez écrire votre propre réponse et y expliquer vos raisonnements... Ne commencez pas svp la guerre d'ajouts.

Comment: @Oreste: Pas de guerre de commentaires (nous sommes servis par ailleurs), je corrige simplement une faute de grammaire.

Comment: @Toto Mais ce n'est pas une faute... jlliagre a écrit qq part une réponse semblable. Sous l'une de mes questions.

Comment: @Oreste: Si, c'est une faute, je me base sur le *Bescherelle*, qui, me semble-t-il, est une référence tout-à-fait valide.

Comment: @Toto, je crois que c'était ma première contribution ici (en total j'en ai fait deux) et je ne comprends pas bien votre réaction.  Si j'ai commis une "faute" en reproduisant la question initiale dans ma réponse, j'en suis désolé, je ne savais pas que c'était interdit.Je ne commettrai plus cette erreur grâce à vous

Comment: @Tsundoku Faute ou pas, la modification de Toto entre en contradiction à la fois avec la question d'Oreste et avec la volonté de tonton gerrit. Elle n'a pas de raison d'être imposée.

Comment: @Tsundoku +1 avec jlliagre. En outre, verbe "pouvoir" est un verbe modale, donc les règles sont un peu différentes. En plus, justement, après que j'ai écrit ces commentaies, Toto a mis un minus à mes trois questions. Enfin, je pense que, logiquement, c'est lui, car ces questions ne sont pas pires que les précédentes. C'est abusif et injuste, et les modérateurs doivent mettre fin à ce genre de compertement.

Comment: @Toto Il est très vrai que « Si tu travailles tu réussirais. » ne se dit pas et qu'il faut dire « Si tu travailles tu réussiras. » ou « si tu travaillais tu réussirais ».

Comment: @LPH: Absolument, mais les corrections que j'ai voulu apporter sont refusées ;-(

Comment: @Toto je n'aimais pas la façon  dont tu l'as fait. Tu n'aurais pas dû imposer ton point de vue. Alors que tu aurais pu écrire ton avis, sans le forcer, et j'aurais été très heureuse de te lire. Le résultat de ce "super contrôle" et surtout de tout ce qui a été déclenché est que Gerrit est parti, et que pour moi aussi, tout cela est désagréable. // LPH + Toto, "pouvoir" est un verbe modale. Ce que LPH a écrit, c'est vrai pour des verbes ordinaires. Mais, à mon avis, _si tu travailles, tu pourrai**s** réussir_ est correct. Je me souviens très bien, j'ai posé une question semblable,

Comment: 2 ou 3 personnes m'ont dit que ça ne marche pas pour les verbes modales non plus, mais jlliagre pense que oui. J'ai réfléchi, je crois que j'ai cherché de l'information, et, maintenant, je pense que jlliagre a raison.

Comment: @Oreste: Je n'essaie pas d'imposer *mon* point de vue, je dis simplement les règles de grammaire concernant la concordance des temps, libre à toi de ne pas les respecter et d'écrire des phrases incorrectes ; dans ce cas je ne comprends pas l'intérêt de poser la question. Bonne journée.